# Does car alternator speed increase during load dump?

Tags: power-supply, automotive, load, surge-protection, alternator

I am  trying to understand the mechanism of voltage surges during load dump in automobiles.
As per this [article](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/loaddump-protection-for-24v-automotive-applications.html) -

> The load-dump event has two components. *First is the pulse amplitude (VP), which depends on the alternator speed* and the level of the alternator's field excitation at the time when the battery is disconnected.

[image]

**Figure**: Output voltage of an alternator during a load-dump event showing nominal battery voltage

1. Assuming the field excitation system and fuel injection system takes some time to respond, during load dump, the alternator speed will increase and cause voltage surges. Is this understanding correct?
2. Subsequently, is the control mechanism through field excitation only or both? That is, engine speed control (throttle) and field control.

I guess we need both as finally output power should match the input power and hence engine power outout could be reduced.

3. The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_dump) article mentions only field control

> ".. but the vehicle's voltage regulator cannot quickly cause the field current to decrease sufficiently, so the alternator continues to generate a large `current`. This large `current` causes the voltage on the vehicle bus to increase significantly -- well above the normal and regulated level."

Shouldn't it be voltage and not current? Large current usually causes voltage dips.

Comment: (From the article: `In automotive systems, a load-dump transient occurs when an alternator is delivering current to a battery and the battery is abruptly removed.`) I'd be surprised if there was a control path from "alternator voltage" to fuel injection/throttle. Or a significant change in alternator speed, at that.

Comment: No units on the x-axis of the plot. What is the time constant of the decay?

Comment: Many alternators had a surge diode fitted on the output that would blow when the battery was disconnected - or a large transient caused by trying to start a car connected by jump leads when the engine was running.

Comment: @greybeard: What would cause the voltage surge if there is no change ( increase) in alternator speed?

Comment: (I don't know. I don't buy en.wikipedia's explanation. Maybe it's (a consequence of) the model of the standard bodies involved more than what happens in the exact case, *not* implying they pull something like this out of thin air.)

Comment: (I can assure you the motor and alternator don't rev up to four to ten times the speed before load dump *in 10 ms* even in idle.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the engine speed control is not linked to the alternator load dump protection on any vehicle I know. They are separate systems. The alternator just spins at whatever speed the driver requires from the engine, and the regulator adjusts the field current to maintain a constant output voltage. When the alternator load is lost the engine/vehicle might speed up a bit, but this would be very slow as the alternator is only a few 100s of watts, and not fast enough to contribute to the load dump pulse.

When the load dump occurs, the problem is that the regulator cannot cut the field winding current fast enough to prevent an increase in the output voltage from the loss of the attached load. This load was drawing a current which resulted in a resistive loss over the alternator windings, and an armature reaction field which reduces the effect of the rotor field, and the regulator was boosting the field current to compensate. There is also an inductive kick component to the load dump pulse, but this is generally easier to deal with.

Note a couple of things though - in my experience, load dump is something you just don't have to worry about on modern vehicles (i.e. anything after 2000 really). The vehicle will have a centralised clamping diode, more than likely integrated into the rectifier/regulator box that sits on the alternator. Ultimately vehicle manufacturers have the same problems with load dump as after market component manufacturers, and it's much more economical to put a centralised load dump suppressor in than have to fit one to ever single ECU on the vehicle bus, so this is what they do.

Of course you may still need to meet the requirements if you're an OEM and your customer asks you too.

Comment: ahh!! Armature reaction is the part I missed!!

I was wondering how the voltage varies if speed and field current remain same! ( V= N* dphi/dt)

Comment: @DivyaK.S Yes, it's largely ignored these days with the prevalence of low permeability permanent magnet machines, but car alternators are pretty low tech.